# Why is this happening? SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Tags: python, return, syntax-error

Can anyone please help. I am facing error in very simple python code. Code is below

```py
if 1950<year<2019 and 1<month<12 \
    and 1<day<31 and 0<hour<24 \
    and 0<minute<60 and 0<second<60:
        return 1
```

Error is:

```py
    return 1
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Comment: You have a `return` outside of a function.  Perhaps you meant to put all your code inside a function.

Comment: The ```return``` statement in python can only be used a function. If this snippet is not in a function, maybe try changing a variable such as ```returner``` to 1.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you are using `return` without a function, so have two options:

- Use `sys.exit("some error message")` instead of `return` which results in an exit code of 1 (note that `sys.exit()` without args means “successful termination”).
- Create a function and place your code within as suggested by @quamrana.

Answer (score 2):

The Python `return` statement is a special statement you can use inside a function or method to send the function's result back to the caller.

Put your piece of code into a function like this; the function's name can be anything.

```
def main():
    if (
        1950 < year < 2019
        and 1 < month < 12
        and 1 < day < 31
        and 0 < hour < 24
        and 0 < minute < 60
        and 0 < second < 60
    ):
        return 1
```

Now, if you want a return to return something from a function, then you have to call the function like this:

```
main()
```

> A return statement consists of the return keyword followed by an
> optional return value. The return value of a Python function can be
> any Python object.

For more explanation visit [understanding-the-python-return-statement](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/#understanding-the-python-return-statement)

Comment: as per your suggestion. I tried using indentation, but the code didn't work.

Comment: It was formatted using the black package, you have to go with your normal indented block.